# Logging wrong passwords in /var/log/auth.log

Tags: security, logs, password

/var/log/auth.log logs (among other things) failed login attempts to my Debian Linux.

I was wondering if it is possible to ask it to log the password that was used in the failed attempt.

This is out of curiosity as to the nature of those failed attempts.
Are they using dictionaries? Combinations of words? Length of passwords used?

I feel that knowing the passwords that are being tried might help me to better understand the level of risk posed by those attempts.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible but I'm sure it is definitely not something that even **should** be possible as this leaks any passwords that are entered with as little mistake as a single typo. If you've ever made a typo while entering your password (and there's no single man on Earth that hasn't) then you'd never even want that to happen.

Comment: @epeleg: assuming Linux and other supported platforms, you could presumably write your own PAM module to achieve what you want. Clearly modules like `pam_unix.so` and `pam_cracklib.so` have access to the password.

Comment: @0xC0000022L, as fas as I remember they have access to hash, not the password itself. epeleg, from security point of view this is very bad idea.

Comment: @RomeoNinov: I guess your memory betrays you. How would `pam_cracklib` be able to check for palindromes, passwords containing the username and similar conditions merely based on the hash?

Comment: @0xC0000022L, probably :) But my humble opinion is not to store passwords in log file :)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.
I do understand and also agree with what Erathiel wrote about typos in correct password. 
It not something I wanted to have as an ongoing default - just something I wanted temporarily to understand what those hackers are trying to do...
can someone elaborate on the PAM thing ? I have a wide development background but not so much linux related background...

Comment: Late comment here - even logging the user name associated with a failed login attempt is likely to leak passwords - how many times have you logged into something and inadvertently typed your password into the user id field because you didn't quite hit the tab key?  And once you start leaking passwords, you've lost password security and therefore accountability and non-repudiation.  Any user can then claim, "You're leaking passwords!  How do you know that was me?"  Because you won't know any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it can be done and I'll show how to here, it is **strongly recommended not to do this** in general case.
Since you basically have passwords sitting around in your log file thus compromising the basic assumption that only you know your password.

You can do it the trick mentioned in  [this](https://hackernoon.com/how-ive-captured-all-passwords-trying-to-ssh-into-my-server-d26a2a6263ec) blog post,
You edit a line in one of the files of OpenSSH, then compile it and use it.
Short version, just run following script:

```
OPENSSH=/opt/openssh2
mkdir -p /opt/openssh2/dist/
cd ${OPENSSH}
wget http://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
tar xvfz zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
cd zlib-1.2.11
./configure --prefix=${OPENSSH}/dist/ && make && make install
cd ${OPENSSH}
wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz
tar xvfz openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.1e
./config --prefix=${OPENSSH}/dist/ && make && make install
cd ${OPENSSH}
wget https://ftp.eu.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-6.2p1.tar.gz
tar xvfz openssh-6.2p1.tar.gz
cd openssh-6.2p1
sed -e 's/struct passwd \* pw = authctxt->pw;/logit("Honey: Username: %s Password: %s", authctxt->user, password);\nstruct passwd \* pw = authctxt->pw;/' -i auth-passwd.c
./configure --prefix=${OPENSSH}/dist/ --with-zlib=${OPENSSH}/dist --with-ssl-dir=${OPENSSH}/dist/ && make && make install
```

For the long and interesting version, read the blog post.

Comment: Never, ever, *ever*, ***EVER*** do this on any sensitive system - or any system that shares users with a sensitive system because users reuse passwords.  Once you do this, you lose all accountability and [non-repudiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-repudiation).  Have an employee you think did some bad things?  "Wasn't me - you're logging all passwords, aren't you?"  Ooops.

Comment: @AndrewHenle added a security warning at the start of the post. Thanks for the constructive feedback.